# Why is the required attribue not changing to false in my Symfony 5 formbuilder?

Tags: debugging, required, formbuilder, symfony5

Lately I have started learning Symfony 5 with video tutorials and the documentation. As I was creating a form with the form builder, I wanted the slug field to fill automatically, but to do so I need to remove the required attribute from it. Problem is, sending `required=>false` to the builder doesn't change anything. I even tried setting `required=>false` for all the fields but no luck. When I dump what I return, I do get an array containing the value I passed, but it won't take effect.

I searched on the internet, asked my friends for help and I'm out of ideas. Could you help me bring some light to this problem ?

Here is the code, if you need more I can provide more. Thanks in advance.

```
class AdType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * Permet d'avoir la configuration de base d'un champ !
     *
     * @param string $label
     * @param string $placeholder
     * @param array $options
     * @return array
     */
    private function getConfiguration($label, $placeholder, $options = []) {
        return array_merge_recursive([
            'label' => $label,
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => $placeholder,
            ]
        ],
        $options);

    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class, $this->getConfiguration("Titre", "Tapez un super titre pour votre annonce"))
            ->add(
                'slug',
                TextType::class,
                $this->getConfiguration("Adresse web", "Tapez l'adresse web (automatique)"),
                [
                    'required' => false,
                ]
            )
            ->add('coverImage', UrlType::class, $this->getConfiguration("URL de l'image principale", "Donnez l'adresse d'une image qui donne vraiment envie"))
            ->add('introduction', TextType::class, $this->getConfiguration("Introduction", "Donnez une description globale de l'annonce"))
            ->add('content', TextareaType::class, $this->getConfiguration("Description détaillée", "Tapez une description qui donne vraiment envie de venir chez vous"))
            ->add('rooms', IntegerType::class, $this->getConfiguration("Nombre de chambres", "Le nombre de chambres disponibles"))
            ->add('price', MoneyType::class, $this->getConfiguration("Prix par nuit", "Indiquez le prix que vous voulez pour une nuit"))
            ->add(
                'images',
                CollectionType::class,
                [
                      'entry_type' => ImageType::class,
                      'allow_add' => true
                ]
            )
        ;
    }
```

Comment: If you want the slug to be filled automatically, why are you adding it to the form ?

Comment: I was following a tutorial and the author made it that way, and it worked for him... This code works perfect on symfony 4, but not on version 5. I am kind of disappointed since I chose symfony because it is said to be very compatible with version 4

Comment: It is compatible, and the SF5 form api is kinda the same as SF4,  I think your error might be elsewhere than the code you've provided, maybe you missed something in your tutorial

Comment: Well I checked 10 times already, I even asked a friend to try it on Symfony 4 and he had no problem disabling the required attribute which did not show up in the html element... My installation is clean and I did not touch any settings at all. I could solve the problem by manually removing the required attribute with jquerry but it wouldn't be a good practice I believe :/ .

Comment: The required attribute is only here to set required on the generated html, it does not do anything else. Your problem is elsewhere, you have to provide more details, controller code,etc